# Getting GPS metadata from a picture with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metadata, paperclip, jpeg, user-experience

I have a question about Paperclip. Many modern cameras and phones add GPS metadata to a photo when taken:

[image: geotagging]

Users of my Rails app can upload photos and manually add the location data to them. However, this sucks as users don't want to enter that: they want it to be there **automatically**.

Can, and how can I get GPS metadata from a photo (always JPEG) with Paperclip and Ruby on Rails? Can it be done with Paperclip or do I need another gem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you need is being able to **extract EXIF** information from the picture.

There is a gem that aims to do just that: `exifr`

You can install it automatically with the following bundler line:

```
gem 'exifr'
```

**EDIT:**

I have personally switched to this fork of the same gem, which contains GPS helpers:

```
gem 'exifr', :git => 'git://github.com/picuous/exifr.git'
```

Use example:

```
EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').gps?                # => true
EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').gps                 # => [37.294112,-122.789422]
EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').gps_lat             # => 37.294112
EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').gps_lng             # =>-122.789422
```

Comment: how would this work with remote assets that have been uploaded by Carrierwave and reside on S3?  If you pass a full URL would it work?

Comment: @amaseuk I may be wrong, but I think that you only can use this with local files. But have a try and let us know

Comment: I would like to note that the "official" gem now has gps helpers also :)

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it with paperclip. rmagick will help you neither. The only way I see is:

```
raw_props = %x[identify -format '%[exif:*]' #{path_to_image}].split("\n").collect{|a| a.split("=")}
properties = Hash[*raw_props.collect { |v| [v, v*2]}.flatten]
```

(pre: imagemagick installed and in the path, check with 'which identify')

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to the accepted answer above, which greatly helped me to get EXIFR working but has few issues:

1. To check if an image has GPS, I had to use `EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').exif?`
2. To pull the latitude I used `EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').gps_latitude`
3. And longitude is `EXIFR::JPEG.new('IMG_6841.JPG').gps_longitude`

Small issues but they had me spinning for a bit and might save someone time down the road.

Also, once I got my GPS coordinates from my photo I found this blog entry to help convert them from an array to Google Map friendly coordinates (i.e. 34.360826, -110.239368): http://www.cloudspace.com/blog/2009/02/16/decoding-gps-latitude-and-longitude-from-exif-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

If you want use "higher level" solution (no exif directly), there is a gem https://github.com/aufi/photo_geoloader which loads latitude, longitude and altitude and can place it into rails model (in callback)

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create do
    PhotoGeoloader.new(photo.path).place_attributes self
  end
  ...
```